# I ran react-native link realm but still getting error

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, realm

I'm testing out `Realm` and would like to make my simple program work.  I followed all the official documentation (https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#getting-started) to get started but some how I'm still getting this  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj0kJ.png) saying I need to run `react-native link realm` that of which I've already done.

How would I fix this issue?

Here's `index.ios.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import Database from './components/Database';

export default class Realm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Database/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Realm', () => Realm);
```

Here's my `Database.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
const Realm = require('realm');

class Database extends Component {
    render() {
        let realm = new Realm({
        schema: [{name: 'Dog', properties: {name: 'string'}}]
    });

    realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Rex'});
});

    return (
    <View>
        <Text>
        Count of Dogs in Realm: {realm.objects('Dog').length}
        </Text>
    </View>
    );
    }
}

export default Database;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should now use **Realm** as your main class' name, as it is the library name, how about trying this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import Database from './components/Database';

export default class YourApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <Database/>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourApp', () => YourApp);
```

Besides, as other lines of code is written in ES6, so in you `Database.js`, instead of using `const Realm = require('realm');`, you can try:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
```

If the problem still persists, maybe you will have to link the 'realm' library manually (as also found in the link you provided)